# Flex - How to change xml attribute name?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

For example I want to change

```
<item id="1"/>
```

to

```
<item code="1"/>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [setName](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/XML.html#setName%28%29) to change the attribute name:

Here for example change all your `id` attributes with `code`:

```
var xmlTest:XML=<r><item id="1"/></r>;

for each (var node:XML in xmlTest.item.descendants("@id"))
 node.setName("code");

trace(xmlTest);
```